# Weird logarithm rules in an attempt to proof an upper bound of JSD between two Gaussian distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions, divergence-operator, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on my thesis in Deep Learning and stumbled upon one paper that I think is really related to my topic. In short, I could not understand some parts of its computation process. Here's the link to the part of the equation that I don't understand:

[The Screenshot of the part of the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqnJH.png)

I cannot understand the transition from Eq.20->21->22. My current guess, for now, is the Eq. 21 is missing its bracket around the

$\log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} + \log \frac{r(x)}{p(x)} $

But even if it's true, I don't understand the transformation from the Eq. 21 to 22. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Many thanks for the tips @Sou燈馬想 , any idea on the link between eq 21 and eq 22?

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is an inequality (not an equality). In fact, it uses the convexity of the negative $\log$ function.

In generate, for a convex function $f$ you have
$$
f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.
$$

And yes, the brackets are missing in the text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand why $\log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} + \log \frac{r(x)}{p(x)}$ is the same as $f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ and why $\log \frac{\frac{\left[q(x)+r(x)\right]}{2}}{p(x)}$ is the same as $\frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}$ ? So sorry for the newbie question

Comment: It is the other way around, and with $a=q(x)/p(x)$ and $b=r(x)/p(x).$

Comment: and the $f$ is $\log$?

Comment: another question, if it is the other way around, the inequality notation in the paper should've been the other way around too?

Comment: Actually, you are right, something is strange with the text, the $1/2$ is also missing.

Comment: Do you think there is something wrong with the paper's calculation? and will it affect the equations after that one?